# Como ocultar barra do top (título e logo) do iframe Youtube

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Depois da Atualização  da API do Youtube em setembro, o comando de "showinfo=0"  parou de funcionar nos iframes.
Existe alguma forma de ocultar essa barra do top (Título, logo, opção de compartilhar e visualizar mais tarde)?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra questão:
É possível inserir uma classe dentro da estrutura o iframe (após o #document) ou inserir linha de código css? Caso sim, como poderia fazer com jQuery?

Código iframe:

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qh67zg05tHM?&amp;theme=dark&amp;autohide=2&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3" showinfo="0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="lazyloaded" data-was-processed="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Se colocasse o código na pergunta facilitaria bastante. ;)

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, inseri o código fonte do iframe.

Comment: Não achei uma forma de esconder, e na documentação https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo tb  não da essa opção... O jeito que consegui foi colocando o vídeo dentro de uma div e escondendo o pedaço dele que tem essas informações, mas da forma que eu fiz o topo do vídeo perde alguns pixels... Tipo tendo essa sua imagem como exemplo é como se eu ocultasse essa parte do quadra vermelho ai corta um pedaço da cabeça da mulher entende. Se quiser monto um exemplo pra vc ver

Comment: Tem que tomar cuidado com isso porque modificar a aparência do player sem ser pela API pode causar problema de violação dos Termos do Youtube.

Comment: Esse é um grande problema @Sam.

Comment: @hugocsl, sua dica é uma boa, mas também um problema. 
Como o site que estou inserindo os vídeos são de projetos da própria organização, não ficara legal cortar.
A grande questão e que preciso apenas esconder o título. Pensei em tentar carregar a miniatura do vídeo e manter por cima,é possível fazer isso e de forma automática?

Comment: Cara se vc não quiser cortar vc tb pode por um outro elemento por cima desse iframe, tipo uma barra preta com algum texto ou algo do tipo, mesmo assim uma parte do topo do vídeo ficaria oculta por traz dessa barra. Sobre a "miniatura" da uma olhada nessa resposta, pode ter algo que te interessa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334350/como-%C3%A9-criado-aqueles-videos-de-preview-em-alguns-sites-tube/335519#335519 Se as estatísticas do vídeo não te interessam, vc tb pode upar o vídeo para o Youtube e não colocar um título, ou colocar colo título um ponto "." ou um "-" se o Youtube permitir

Comment: @hugocsl, colocar um elemento em cima, apenas se for a miniatura do vídeo, porém e quase impossível fazer isso de forma automática. Poderia utilizar as miniaturas geradas pelo Youtube, mas não tem como saber qual é a maior resolução da miniatura que vai estar disponível, o que impacta na hora de configurar o PHP para gerar isso automático. :(
PS: esses vídeos (id's) serão incluso em uma área específica do Wordpres e posteriormente serão carregados com a estrutura salva no php.